# Issues SSHing to Raspberry Pi From External IP

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been trying to SSH to my RPi from an external network for a while with little luck. I've followed all the guides and they say all the same things: get SSH set up, port forward on port 22, and then connect using your external IP address. I've been able to easily SSH to the RPi using my internal IP from the same network with no problem, but not from my external IP. This is my configuration for port forwarding:

[image]

That is the internal IP for my RPi's ethernet connection. I've tried it with the IP for WiFi as well and it just has the same effect. When I try to SSH using my external IP, it just times out no matter which internal IP is port forwarded (ethernet or WiFi). I've tried it both on PuTTY on my PC and from my Macbook using

`sudo ssh pi@my.external.ip.address`

It still just times out. The only thing I can think that might be happening is some issue with a firewall, but I have no idea how firewalls work so if this has been seen before and it is a firewall issue, more detailed guide would be nice.

Even if the issue is not known, is there any way to debug the SSH call and see where exactly it's failing when I use the external IP? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ssh -v -v -v pi@my.external.ip.address` will print what exactly it was doing. You wouldn't happen trying to connect to your external IP from your internal lan, would you?

Comment: No downvotes from me, and while an interesting problem, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Yeah, I considered posting on a different site but I thought that I may as well just post here because it is kind of a general SSH question and someone probably knows the answer

Comment: And alvits, I am trying to connect to the external IP from my internal LAN just for testing, although I have 2 routers in my house and tried connecting to the WiFi of the other router and seeing if I could SSH to the external IP and that didn't work either. However if connecting to the external IP from the same WiFi is an issue I would imagine a different router connected to the same modem might also be an issue. What makes that bad exactly?

Comment: Tried from an external network, still doesn't work :/

Comment: You can't test from a different router connected to the same modem. The public IP address is assigned to the modem's partner, not the router (typically is a class A RFC-1918). If you can't connect to it from public , such as internet cafes, then your ISP is blocking `ssh` connections and probably more. However, if you check the IP address received by the router, you should be able to connect to it from another router connected to the same modem.

Comment: Yeah I tested from a friend's house and it didn's work, so i would assume ssh is being blocked bymy ISP

Comment: Remember, your public IP is different from your router's public IP. Router's public IP is actually NATted from ISP. From your internal LAN, go to http://www.myipaddress.com and copy the IP address you see. This is your public IP. This is the IP you should connect to when connecting from outside such as internet cafes.

Comment: I know, i did, and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled through a lot of this with my pi. As alvits suggests, if you are trying to connect to the pi via the LAN it probably won't work. You need to test from an external IP address.

You shouldn't need to sudo either.

If you are still using pi/raspberry as the username and password, change ASAP. Once the firewall is open it won't take long before you start to see bots trying to log in. I think it was about 30 minutes on my machine. It was interesting for a few days, then annoying. Almost all attacks stopped when I moved off of port 22.

Comment: I was testing with WiFi from a different router connected to the same modem, however I just checked out the external IP address on that connection and it's (not that surprisingly) the same. That might be my issue, I'll try connecting next time I'm somewhere other than my house. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/enabling-SSH/td-p/509945), it does not appear that my router supports SSH. I was able to find guides online of how to enable it using custom firmware, however I probably won't be attempting that. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: No. They were talking about `ssh` access to the router, not ssh forwarding. Administration of routers/wifis are strictly https.

Comment: @alvits ok, that does seem to make more sense. I guess I'll have to go through more troubleshooting then